# How to store slovak characters from files in Visual Studio using C++. (čšť..)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, utf-8

I have a problem with storing slovak characters from csv file. I am using C++ and Visual studio IDE. I can read it, store it and output to console. In the console characters appear to be normal. But when I open "locals" where are the actual string values stored the characters arent stored right. I need this for filtering that i'll do and the characters in "locals" need to be stored right altought on console they appear right.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "Better" would be to use [utf8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out. I needed to change the input CSV file coding from UTF-8 to ANSI. The characters are now stored in locals right.

Comment: They are stored “right” with UTF-8 also. the default *display* for locals is ANSI. See [format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp?view=vs-2022). Add `,s8` after a variable to display it decoded as UTF8 instead of ANSI.